# How to use answer (from command window) for a code

Tags: matlab

I have random matrix(A) and I find a result I'd like to use later for my code

```
A=randint(5,7,[1,9])
ans A =

     8     1     2     2     6     7     7
     9     3     9     4     1     7     1
     2     5     9     9     8     4     3
     9     9     5     8     9     6     1
     6     9     8     9     7     2     1
```

How can I now get:

```
A = [8,1,2,2,6,7,7;9,3,9...7,2,1];
```

without having to type it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought of another way. Your goal is to have A in your script - right?

You can just paste it as follows:

```
A = [
     8     1     2     2     6     7     7
     9     3     9     4     1     7     1
     2     5     9     9     8     4     3
     9     9     5     8     9     6     1
     6     9     8     9     7     2     1 
 ]
```

(note the square brackets)

It will evaluate to your original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has a function for that: [MAT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2str.html)

```
>> A = randi([1,9],[5,7]);
>> mat2str(A)
ans =
[5 5 7 5 3 2 5;5 6 5 3 8 4 1;9 8 8 1 7 9 6;1 5 5 1 8 6 3;3 4 5 8 9 9 5]
```

This is suitable for use with EVAL

Answer (score 0):

Make the string yourself:

```
Str = ['[' sprintf('%i',A(1)) sprintf(',%i',A(2:end)) ']']
```

Note this string does not contain any `;` as in your example. so when you evaluate it you will get a 1x35 vector (instead of the original 5x7matrix)

So easiest way to fix this would be to add after you evaluate the string.

```
A = reshape(A,5,7)
```

It will look like

```
B = [....
B = reshape(B,5,7)
```

Comment: I entered what you have written and Matlab reports unexpected Matlab expression

Comment: Ah I see. Forgot a bracket. That's what happens when you don't have a matlab at home for your comments :)

Comment: could you please retype it. I don't know which bracket you mean. Thanks

Comment: The code in the answer should now work. The second sprintf openend two ( but closed only one.

Comment: ok, this string gives me a vector in a way I asked, but this reshape thing gives me matrix(A) in the same way I had it in the beginning, without brackets and all.

Comment: When you pur the string in your program A = [.... you will get a vector 1x35. To get the original 5x7 matrix you need to add this reashape in the code.